# Убрать background-image из кода информера погоды

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть задача, убрать background-image с кода информера погоды. Проблема в том, что если убрать класс `class="booked-wzs-160-110"`из HTML кода, то перестаёт подгружаться актуальные данные погоды, зависает информер. Пробовал прописывать перед классом `style="background-image: none !important;"` Но что бы я не прописывал в этом стайле, ничего не меняется - почему то просто постоянно прописано `background-color: #transparent;` и никуда не деться. Я в javascript не силён, может в нём что то нужно прописать?

```js
< script type = "text/javascript"
charset = "UTF-8"
src = "http://widgets.booked.net/weather/info?action=get_weather_info&ver=4&cityID=18901&type=1&scode=124&ltid=3539&domid=589&cmetric=1&wlangID=20&color=transparent&wwidth=250&header_color=ffffff&text_color=333333&link_color=08488D&border_form=1&footer_color=ffffff&footer_text_color=333333&transparent=0" > < /script>

<script type="text/javascript
"> var css_file=document.createElement("
link "); css_file.setAttribute("
rel ","
stylesheet "); css_file.setAttribute("
type ","
text / css "); css_file.setAttribute("
href ",'//s.bookcdn.com/css/w/booked-wzs-widget-160.css?v=0.0.1'); document.getElementsByTagName("
head ")[0].appendChild(css_file); function setWidgetData(data) { if(typeof(data) != 'undefined' && data.results.length > 0) { for(var i = 0; i < data.results.length; ++i) { var objMainBlock = document.getElementById('m-booked-bl-simple-7511'); if(objMainBlock !== null) { var copyBlock = document.getElementById('m-bookew-weather-copy-'+data.results[i].widget_type); objMainBlock.innerHTML = data.results[i].html_code; if(copyBlock !== null) objMainBlock.appendChild(copyBlock); } } } else { alert('data=undefined||data.results is empty'); } } </script>
```

```html
<div style="    position: absolute;
    right: 13px;
    top: -148px;
    z-index: 999;" id="m-booked-bl-simple-7511">
  <a href="//nochi.com/weather/tbilisi-18901" style="background-image: none !important;" class="booked-wzs-160-110">
    <div class="booked-wzs-160-data wrz-01">
      <div class="booked-wzs-160-right">
        <div class="booked-wzs-day-deck">
          <div class="booked-wzs-day-val">
            <div class="booked-wzs-day-number"><span class="plus">+</span>21</div>
            <div class="booked-wzs-day-dergee">
              <div class="booked-wzs-day-dergee-val">&deg;</div>
              <div class="booked-wzs-day-dergee-name">C</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="booked-wzs-day">
            <div class="booked-wzs-day-d"><span class="plus">+</span>21&deg;</div>
            <div class="booked-wzs-day-n"><span class="plus">+</span>7&deg;</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="booked-wzs-160-city">Тбилиси</div>
        <div class="booked-wzs-160-date">Воскресенье, 24</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="booked-wzs-center"> <span class="booked-wzs-bottom-l">Прогноз на неделю</span> 
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<!-- weather widget end -->
```

Теперь добавлю код инспектора.

```css
element.style {
  background-color: #transparent;
}
.booked-wzs-160-110 {
  background-image: url('//s.bookcdn.com/images/we160x110.png') !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  display: block !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 160px !important;
  height: 110px !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  font: normal 11px/11px verdana, sans-serif !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  border: none !important;
  text-align: left !important;
```

```html
<div style="    position: absolute;
    right: 13px;
    top: -148px;
    z-index: 999;" id="m-booked-bl-simple-7511">
  <a href="//nochi.com/weather/tbilisi-18901" class="booked-wzs-160-110" style="background-color:#transparent;">
    <div class="booked-wzs-160-data wrz-18">
      <div class="booked-wzs-160-right">
        <div class="booked-wzs-day-deck">
          <div class="booked-wzs-day-val">
            <div class="booked-wzs-day-number"><span class="plus">+</span>21</div>
            <div class="booked-wzs-day-dergee">
              <div class="booked-wzs-day-dergee-val">°</div>
              <div class="booked-wzs-day-dergee-name">C</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="booked-wzs-day">
            <div class="booked-wzs-day-d"><span class="plus">+</span>22°</div>
            <div class="booked-wzs-day-n"><span class="plus">+</span>14°</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="booked-wzs-160-city">Тбилиси</div>
        <div class="booked-wzs-160-date">Понедельник, 25</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="booked-wzs-center"> <span class="booked-wzs-bottom-l">Прогноз на неделю</span> 
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Для начала, я бы попробовал не прописывать стили в html-атрибуте `style`, а описать их в css файле, с тем же модификатором `!important`. Тогда они будут иметь приоритет над стилями, добавляемыми скриптом, если только в них тоже не используется `!important`

Comment: @VenZell Я не могу добавить еще один класс. Он как будто не прописывается, браузер его не отображает.

Comment: @BamNait код из инспектора скинь у этого элемента, и `CSS` и `html`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев добавил, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно сразу после кода информера поставить:

```
<style>
.booked-wzs-160-110 { background-image: none !important; }
</style>
```

Если просто добавить этот код в стили, то эффекта не будет.

Чтобы убрать дождевое облако и другие символы погоды, нужно сделать то же самое с .booked-wzs-160-data

В окне выдачи информера стоит запрет на изменения в коде информера, но в этом решении код информера никто и не трогает.

```html
<!-- weather widget start --><div id="m-booked-bl-simple-70303"> <a href="//nochi.com/weather/tbilisi-18901" class="booked-wzs-160-110" style="background-color:#137AE9;"> <div class="booked-wzs-160-data wrz-18"> <div class="booked-wzs-160-right"> <div class="booked-wzs-day-deck"> <div class="booked-wzs-day-val"> <div class="booked-wzs-day-number"><span class="plus">+</span>18</div> <div class="booked-wzs-day-dergee"> <div class="booked-wzs-day-dergee-val">&deg;</div> <div class="booked-wzs-day-dergee-name">C</div> </div> </div> <div class="booked-wzs-day"> <div class="booked-wzs-day-d"><span class="plus">+</span>18&deg;</div> <div class="booked-wzs-day-n"><span class="plus">+</span>12&deg;</div> </div> </div> <div class="booked-wzs-160-city">Тбилиси</div> <div class="booked-wzs-160-date">Понедельник, 25</div> </div> </div> <div class="booked-wzs-center"> <span class="booked-wzs-bottom-l">Прогноз на неделю</span> </div> </a> </div><script type="text/javascript"> var css_file=document.createElement("link"); css_file.setAttribute("rel","stylesheet"); css_file.setAttribute("type","text/css"); css_file.setAttribute("href",'//s.bookcdn.com/css/w/booked-wzs-widget-160.css?v=0.0.1'); document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css_file); function setWidgetData(data) { if(typeof(data) != 'undefined' && data.results.length > 0) { for(var i = 0; i < data.results.length; ++i) { var objMainBlock = document.getElementById('m-booked-bl-simple-70303'); if(objMainBlock !== null) { var copyBlock = document.getElementById('m-bookew-weather-copy-'+data.results[i].widget_type); objMainBlock.innerHTML = data.results[i].html_code; if(copyBlock !== null) objMainBlock.appendChild(copyBlock); } } } else { alert('data=undefined||data.results is empty'); } } </script> <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://widgets.booked.net/weather/info?action=get_weather_info&ver=4&cityID=18901&type=1&scode=2&ltid=3540&domid=589&cmetric=1&wlangID=20&color=137AE9&wwidth=250&header_color=ffffff&text_color=333333&link_color=08488D&border_form=1&footer_color=ffffff&footer_text_color=333333&transparent=0"></script><!-- weather widget end -->
<style>
.booked-wzs-160-data, .booked-wzs-160-110 { background-image: none !important; }
</style>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, но мне нужно убрать картинку, которая дает белую рамку и гардиент ближе к верху.

Comment: вижу вы исправили ответ )

Comment: @BamNait Да, увлёкся, и начал сносить всё подряд... ))

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось )

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вспомнить специфичность селекторов. Атрибут style убери. 
Укажи `id="какой_то_айди"`, затем в CSS файле определи его ниже всех остальных селекторов, ну и добавь `!important`. Как вариант.

Comment: Браузер всё ровно не видит ни id ни style. Я в вопросе привел внизу код из браузера.